# Android echo cancellation

Tags: android, audio, echo, cancellation

I'm trying to develop an Audio Capture application using the AudioRecord 
class from android api, setting, how audio source a 
MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, the aplication works, but when I try to use 
the echo cancellation, setting a
MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION how source, when AudioRecorder object is 
created, a IllegalArgumentException throws, but I don't know why:

My code is:

```
private static final int SAMPLE_RATE = 16000;
private static final int BIT_ENCODING = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
private static final int CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO;

private int m_i32BufferSize;

private AudioRecord m_AudioRecorder;

public caudioCapture ()
{
    super ();

    m_i32BufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_RATE, CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION, BIT_ENCODING);

    //Create audio recorder object 
    try
    {
        m_AudioRecorder = new AudioRecord (MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION,SAMPLE_RATE,CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION,BIT_ENCODING,m_i32BufferSize);

    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad arguments on AudioRecorder creation", e);
    }
```

In my android manifest I have:

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"

Maybe it is because I'm using a Samsung galaxy tab p1000 and it run with android 2.2? Any idea?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is correct. The problem is that you are using Android 2.2. The new VOICE_COMMUNICATION got introduced in Android 3.0. When run on older versions you will get the DEFAULT source instead.

Comment: Hello Joakim, but, the DEFAULT source has echo cancellation? Because I need it, and if I use the device's echo cancelator, is better for me. I know that, skype for example, have echo cancellation in android 2.2, but I don't know if they implement their own cancelator or uses some issues of device

Comment: No, the DEFAULT does not. If you need echo cancellation before 3.0 you need to do it your self. I would recommend you to look into Speex. It has a working echo cancellation implementation. It's native code so you need to call it through JNI.

Comment: Well, I have worked with Speex and the echo cancellation it's very expensive, about cpu resources, so, I think that I'll try with the released skype code, however, I don't know if this codec implements cancellation.

Comment: I'm pretty disappointed in the built-in echo cancellation with android 3.0.  I added switches to an app so I could turn it on and off, and the result was noticable, but it was still far from adequate.  I have only tested it with one phone (a Samsung Vibrant running Cyanogen 10), so YMMV.

Answer (score 6):

I was finally able to get echo cancellation to work on my Arm5 (WM8650) processor. Below are the steps I took.

1. I wrapped Speex with JNI and called echo processing routines before sending PCM frames to encoder. No echo was canceled no matter what Speex settings I tried.
2. Because Speex is very sensitive to delay between playback and echo frames I implemented a queue and queued all packets sent to AudioTrack. The size of the queue should be roughly equal to the size of internal AudioTrack buffer. This way packet were sent to echo_playback roughly at the time when AudioTrack send packets to the sound card from its internal buffer. The delay was removed with this approach but echo was still not cancelled
3. I wrapped WebRtc echo cancellation part with JNI and called its methods before sending packets to encoder. The echo was still present but the library obviously was trying to cancel it.
4. I applied the buffer technique described in P2 and it finally started to work. The delay needs to be adjusted for each device though. Note also that WebRtc has mobile and full version of echo cancellation. The full version substantially slows the processor and should probably be run on ARM7 only. The mobile version works but with lower quality

I hope this will help someone.

Comment: hi. Could you please share your jni code here. I am also using speex and getting a lot of echo.